# Is there a way to store addresses in the solidity contract to authorize only those addresses to do transactions?

Tags: solidity, erc20, binance-smart-chain

I'm starting with contracts in solidity and a question arose, is there any way I can store addresses in the wallet so that only these stored can make the withdrawal of coins that I make available? Let me explain better, I want to airdrop for 1 month for example and after this period the people who got my coins can withdraw from my contract, but so that only the people who complied with the airdrop rules. I want to do this so they pay transaction fees. But I want only addresses authorized by the owner of the contract to be able to withdraw the currency

Comment: Only some authorized addresses do a function like receiving airdrop tokens?!

Comment: That's what I'm trying to create, a list of addresses authorized by the owner of the contract to make the transaction

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this, in order to avoid gas, is to either use merkle trees or signatures. I have implemented signatures in two NFT projects.
Basically, for every address you wish to whitelist, you sign a message offchain, by using a wallet in your possession (it can be empty, you only need to sign messages).

Example call for signing via JavaScript (by using the web3js lib):

```
web3.eth.accounts.sign(message, privateKey);
```

By using the privateKey, this allows you to sign multiple messages at once (without having to confirm in MetaMask. It is clear that: please keep that private key as safe as possible! Only execute this code locally on your machine! Do not store the privateKey in any text file, especially not in the project folder, that might get synched to github!

The other way of doing it via MetaMask:

```
web3.eth.personal.sign(message, from);
```

(where "from" is the address of the signer).

On the contract side, there are some functions that can be used to retrieve the signer of a message, by reconstructing the message and passing the signature you have generated.

Some reference code:

```
    // used to keep track of issuer addresses, that can issue whitelists
    mapping(address => bool) internal issuers;

    // builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
    function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns(bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
    }

    // get the signer address by message and signature
    function recoverSigner(bytes32 _message, bytes memory sig) internal pure returns(address){
        uint8 v;
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;

        (v, r, s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(_message, v, r, s);
    }
  
    function signerIsIssuer(bytes memory message, bytes memory _sig, uint256 nonce) public view returns(bool){
        // check the issuer
        if (!issuers[recoverSigner(message, sig)]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true; 
        }
    }

    // splits the signature into its components
    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig) internal pure returns(uint8, bytes32, bytes32){
        require(sig.length == 65);

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
            r:= mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes
            s:= mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
            v:= byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }
    
    // this has to hash the same parameters as on the offchain side
    // do not reuse nonces
    function hashMessage(address authorizedWallet, uint256 nonce) public returns(bytes memory){
      // create the message hash
      bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(authorizedWallet, nonce)));
        if (signerIsIssuer(message, _sig, _nonce)){
          // authorizedWallet really is authorized by signature
        }

    }
```

If you want to be able to remove authorization, then you either need to invalidate the nonce, or work with expiration timestamps or keep an address blacklist. Please note, that once a signature is emitted, if the contract has no ways to be told, that that signature is not valid anymore, the wallet address will be authorized forever.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think Merle trees are overkill (expensive & hard to develop), but the signature solution is really smart.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
contract test{
   address owner;
   mapping(address=>bool) authorizedAddresses;
   mapping(address=>bool) isRegistered;
   mapping(uint256=>address) users;
   uint256 userCounter;

   constructor(){
      owner = msg.sender;
   }

   modifier isOwner(){
      require(msg.sender == owner, "Access denied!");
      _;
   }

   function changeOwner(address _to) public isOwner{
      owner = _to;
   }
   
   function authorizeAddress(address _address) public isOwner{
      if(isRegistered[_address]){
         authorizedAddresses[_address] = true;
      }else{
         users[userCounter] = _address;
         isRegistered[_address] = true;
         authorizedAddresses[_address] = true;
         userCounter ++;
      }
   }
   
   function unauthorizeAddress(address _address) public isOwner{
      require(authorizedAddresses[_address], "User is not authorized already");
      authorizedAddresses[_address] = false;
   }

   modifier isAuthorizedAddress(){
      require(authorizedAddresses[_address], "You are not authorized to call this function");
      _;
   }
```

I should note I did not test this code and may throw error, so if it throws any error let me know and modify it or you can do it let me know how to fix it and edit the code for others.

If you did not understand any part, simply ask to describe :)

Best regards

Comment: Hi Ahmad Gorji, Hi, thanks for the reply, but that's not exactly what I'm thinking because every address I authorize I'll have to pay the gas. What I wanted was the following, the contract would communicate with an external database, if the wallet address was there, the person could carry out the transaction, if not, it would be impossible.

Comment: If you want to store it in external database and use it in contract later you must create an oracle, which I'm sorry, I don't know enough about them

Comment: ok, i will search about it, thanks! Ahmad Gorji

Comment: A contract can never make external calls that are off-chain..this is because of the deterministic nature of the smart contract design. What we do is to get some data from off-chain like from an external database that is we set up a separate contract called `oracle contract`. This oracle contract needs to be called periodically or at a scheduled time to reflect real-world data by an oracle node. There is some service available for simplifying this process. The best one currently is `Chainlink`(https://chain.link/)

Comment: There is an easy solution to save gas: use signed coupons and verify them on-chain. No need for oracle, etc. Please read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ERC20 token standart. Just define allowance for those addresses who complied with the airdrop rules.

Comment: It's pretty expensive to upload thousands of addresses to the blockchain, and also unnecessary: you can just give them signed coupons and verify on-chain

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, you can store addresses in a mapping like `mapping(address=>bool) authorizedAddresses;`

**However, it is expensive and inefficient to store hundreds of addresses on the blockchain.** Think about that, probably you upload a bunch of addresses you don't even need to, because people will forget that they can get the airdrop and they won't even claim it.

**A better approach is to give them signed coupons.** When they claim the airdrop on your website, the transaction submits a coupon and your contract will verify if the coupon is:

- signed by you
- belongs to the sender address
- allowed to claim the amount

It all happens in the background, so users won't notice anything.

**Generate coupons in JS:**

```js
const {
    keccak256,
    toBuffer,
    ecsign,
    bufferToHex
} = require("ethereumjs-util")
const { ethers } = require('ethers')

const PRIV_KEY = "YOUR_SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY"

//utils
function generateHashBuffer(typesArray, valueArray) {
    return keccak256(
        toBuffer(ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(typesArray,
            valueArray))
    )
}

function createCoupon(hash, signerPvtKey) {
    return ecsign(hash, signerPvtKey)
}

function fromHexString(hexString) {
    return Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex'))
}

function serializeCoupon(coupon) {
    return {
        r: bufferToHex(coupon.r),
        s: bufferToHex(coupon.s),
        v: coupon.v,
    }
}

//generate coupon
function generate(claimAmount, address) {
    const userAddress = ethers.utils.getAddress(address) // get checksum-correct address
    
    const hashBuffer = generateHashBuffer(
        ["uint256", "address"],
        [claimAmount, userAddress]
    )
    const coupon = createCoupon(hashBuffer, fromHexString(PRIV_KEY))

    console.log({
        address,
        claimAmount,
        coupon: serializeCoupon(coupon)
    })
}
```

Now you have the coupon, you can **build an API**, so when the user click Claim on your website, he can submit the amount and the signature to the blockchain in the claim transaction.

**Verify signature in your contract:**

```
contract Airdrop is
    Ownable,
    ReentrancyGuard
{
    address private COUPON_SIGNER = 0xYOUR_SIGNER_ADDRESS;
    mapping(address => bool) public CLAIMED_ADDRESSES;

    struct Coupon {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;
    }

    // check that the coupon sent was signed by the admin signer address
    function _isVerifiedCoupon(bytes32 digest, Coupon memory coupon)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        address signer = ecrecover(digest, coupon.v, coupon.r, coupon.s);
        require(signer != address(0), "ECDSA: Invalid whitelist signature.");
        return signer == COUPON_SIGNER;
    }


    // Claim Airdrop
    function claim(uint256 amountToClaim, Coupon memory coupon) external nonReentrant {
        require(
            CLAIMED_ADDRESSES[msg.sender] == false,
            "This address already claimed a refund."
        );
        require(
            address(this).balance >= amountToClaim,
            "Contract balance is too low."
        );
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encode(amountToClaim, msg.sender));
        require(
            _isVerifiedCoupon(digest, coupon),
            "Unexcepted error: unable to verify coupon."
        );

        CLAIMED_ADDRESSES[msg.sender] = true;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amountToClaim); // Send ETH
    }
}
```

PLEASE PLEASE don't just copy this code: TEST, TEST, and TEST. Always write unit tests.